# Get indexes of all occurrences of a substring within a string

Tags: rust

If I wanted to get the index of the **first** occurrence of, say, substring `"foo"` within a string `"foo bar foo baz foo"`, I'd use:

```
fn main() {
    let my_string = String::from("foo bar foo baz foo");
    println!("{:?}", my_string.find("foo"));
}
```

...which would give me `Some(0)`.

However, I need to find indexes of **all** occurrences of a substring within a string.
In this scenario, I'd need something like:

```
[0, 8, 16]
```

How can I do this idiomatically in Rust?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [match_indices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.match_indices). Example from Rust docs:

```rust
let v: Vec<_> = "abcXXXabcYYYabc".match_indices("abc").collect();
assert_eq!(v, [(0, "abc"), (6, "abc"), (12, "abc")]);

let v: Vec<_> = "1abcabc2".match_indices("abc").collect();
assert_eq!(v, [(1, "abc"), (4, "abc")]);

let v: Vec<_> = "ababa".match_indices("aba").collect();
assert_eq!(v, [(0, "aba")]); // only the first `aba`
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the most complete answer, based on the OP's requirement, would be:

```rust
let v: Vec<_> = "abcXXXabcYYYabc".match_indices("abc").map(|(i, _)|i).collect();
assert_eq!(v, [0,6,12]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `match_indices`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.match_indices

```
let v: Vec<_> = "abcXXXabcYYYabc".match_indices("abc").collect();
assert_eq!(v, [(0, "abc"), (6, "abc"), (12, "abc")]);
```